# How to get a key value pair from a Database using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a new to SQL so, can you please help me in figuring out how to get a key-value pair from a SQL 
for example : Table A

```
A(PK)    B(INT)  C       D
------ ------- ------- --------

1        X       Y        Z

2        A       B        C
```

I want the output in the form

```
A = 1
B = X 
C = Y 
D = Z
```

i tried

```
SELECT A,B,C,D from tableA ;
```

But it only prints in the form 1 X Y Z
So, can you please help me ?

Comment: Do you only want a single record's worth of keys?  Is there a column which defines an order?

Comment: yes, it will be a single result query

Comment: Generally getting the column names along with the row values is a thing the SQL client provides for you. What SQL client are you using?

Comment: i'm using pgadmin 4

Comment: Presumably B should contain numbers? It's type integer.

Comment: Yes! i has integers

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with pgAdmin, but I don't believe it's an appropriate tool for getting specific formatting. Also, what would you like done with the second column?

Comment: This kind of column rotation is typically done by the SQL client (e.g. [in psql](https://imgur.com/a/51pLdMC)) However I doubt pgAdmin can do it. Also: how would you like the second _row_ to be displayed?

Comment: The objective is to match column values to column names and fetch them together like col_name = col value, (only one value) so if multiple columns are present then col1 = val1 , col2 = val2 , col3 = val3

Comment: And what about multiple **rows**? What about a JSON result? http://rextester.com/XNB38806

Comment: I'll look into using JSON for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally getting the column names along with the row values and formatting the result is a thing the SQL client provides for you. pgAdmin isn't really suited for this, a programming language would be better.

For example, here's how you'd do it using Ruby and the [ruby-pg gem](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'test' )
conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM tableA" ) do |result|
  result.each do |row|
    row.each do |column,value|
      puts "#{column} = #{value}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: would it be possible in java?

Comment: @Ani Yes, just about any programming language can connect to Postgres. I don't know Java, but this may help. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm

Comment: I used JSON and java to complete this answer, though i didn't use ruby as the language, the idea was pretty much the same Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can do a union of the queries picking one column at a time

```
SELECT 'A', A from tableA WHERE ID = @ID
UNION
SELECT 'B', B from tableA WHERE ID = @ID
UNION
SELECT 'C', C from tableA WHERE ID = @ID
UNION
SELECT 'D', D from tableA WHERE ID = @ID
```

you will probably need to cast all the columns to a common type (varchar) for this to work.

Comment: I added that just to ensure one record, Ani has not specified what clause is used.

Comment: I combined 2 answers here, i tried you answer but didn't work for the time being, but the above 2 answers ( one as reply ) i tried as JSON object and then parsed it using JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a function that returns the result as desired:

```
create type crosstab_type as (row_num bigint, column_name text, value text);

create or replace function kv()
  returns setof crosstab_type
as
$$
declare 
  l_rec record;
  l_row bigint := 1;
begin
  for l_rec in select * from ani 
  loop
    return next (l_row, 'a', l_rec.a::text)::crosstab_type;
    return next (l_row, 'b', l_rec.b::text)::crosstab_type;
    return next (l_row, 'c', l_rec.c::text)::crosstab_type;
    return next (l_row, 'd', l_rec.d::text)::crosstab_type;
    l_row := l_row + 1;
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;



select *
from kv();
```

returns:

```
row_num | column_name | value
--------+-------------+------
      1 | a           | 1    
      1 | b           | X    
      1 | c           | Y    
      1 | d           | Z    
      2 | a           | 2    
      2 | b           | A    
      2 | c           | B    
      2 | d           | C
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/RCKB51862